# using - in a function parameter in perl

Tags: perl, parameters

I have the following

```
use Config::IniFiles;
my $cfg = new Config::IniFiles( -file => "/path/configfile.ini" );
print "The value is " . $cfg->val( 'Section', 'Parameter' ) . "."
if $cfg->val( 'Section', 'Parameter' );
```

Although the above makes almost all sense I wasnt sure what `-file` is denoting

```
my $cfg = new Config::IniFiles( -file => "/path/configfile.ini" );
```

Is the above saying the `$file` param in the funciton gets set to `/path/configfile.ini`? Or is it something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context `-file` is an ordinary string, i.e. the expression can be written as

```
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new("-file" => "/path/configfile.ini");
```

The `=>` operator causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string, so you don't have to quote it.

Comment: Oh so it means nothing special. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

I advice your using modern oop style:

```
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "/path/configfile.ini" );
```

Please check source of this module in CPAN: [Config::IniFiles](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/WADG/Config-IniFiles-2.38/IniFiles.pm)

After -file => "/path/configfile.ini", it save to parameter `$self->{cf} = $v`, and then ReadConfig.

Comment: I am using the modern version, I just copied and pasted the example. Thanks for that

Answer (score -1):

From the [`Config::IniFiles` documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aIniFiles):

> **-file filename**
>
> Specifies a file to load the parameters from. This 'file' may actually
>   be any of the following things:
>
> 1. *the pathname of a file*
>
>    ```
>    $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "/path/to/config_file.ini" );
>    ```
> 2. *a simple filehandle*
>
>    ```
>    $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => STDIN );
>    ```
> 3. *a filehandle glob*
>
>    ```
>    open( CONFIG, "/path/to/config_file.ini" );
>    $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => *CONFIG );
>    ```
> 4. a reference to a glob
>
>    ```
>    open( CONFIG, "/path/to/config_file.ini" );
>    $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => \*CONFIG );
>    ```
> 5. *an `IO::File` object*
>
>    ```
>    $io = IO::File->new( "/path/to/config_file.ini" );
>    $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => $io );
>    ```
>
>    or
>
>    ```
>    open my $fh, '<', "/path/to/config_file.ini" or die $!;
>    $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => $fh );
>    ```
> 6. *A reference to a scalar (requires newer versions of `IO::Scalar`)*
>
>    ```
>    $ini_file_contents = <<EOT
>    [section name]
>    Parameter=A value
>    Setting=Another value
>    EOT
>
>    $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => \$ini_file_contents );
>    ```